# Rotation matrix and inertia tensor

Tags: tensors, coordinate-systems, classical-mechanics

Let $\mathbf{R}$ be the rotation matrix that transforms the reference frame $K$ to $K'$ and $\mathbf{I}$ be the inertia tensor of $K$, $\mathbf{I'}$ be the inertia tensor of $K$. I am asked to show
$$\mathbf{I'}=\mathbf{R}\mathbf{I}\mathbf{R^T}$$
Namely  the components of the moment of inertia tensor $I_{ij}$ in the two references frames are related by $I'_{ij}=\sum_{k,\ell}R_{ik}R_{j\ell}I_{k\ell}$. Below is my attempt:

As the first step we write the expressions of $\mathbf{I}'$ and $\mathbf{I}$, they are
\begin{equation*}
    \mathbf{I}'=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    I_{x_1'x_1'} & I_{x_1'x_2'} & I_{x_1'x_3'}\\
    I_{x_2'x_1'} & I_{x_2'x_2'} & I_{x_2'x_3'}\\
    I_{x_3'x_1'} & I_{x_3'x_2'} & I_{x_3'x_3'}
    \end{pmatrix}
    =
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \int x_2'^2+x_3'^2 & -\int x_1'x_2' & -\int x_3'x_1'\\
    -\int x_1'x_2' & \int x_3'^2+x_1'^2 & -\int x_2'x_3'\\
    -\int x_3'x_1' & -\int x_2'x_3' & \int x_1'^2 +x_2'^2
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    \mathbf{I}=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    I_{x_1x_1} & I_{x_1x_2} & I_{x_1x_3}\\
    I_{x_2x_1} & I_{x_2x_2} & I_{x_2x_3}\\
    I_{x_3x_1} & I_{x_3x_2} & I_{x_3x_3}
    \end{pmatrix}
    =
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \int x_2^2+x_3^2 & -\int x_1x_2 & -\int x_3x_1\\
    -\int x_1x_2 & \int x_3^2+x_1^2 & -\int x_2x_3\\
    -\int x_3x_1 & -\int x_2x_3 & \int x_1^2 +x_2^2
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
We try find the expression of $x_{i}'x_{j}'$ with $i\neq j$. Since
\begin{equation*}
x_i'=\sum_{k}R_{ik}x_k
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
x_{j}'=\sum_{\ell}R_{j\ell}x_{\ell}
\end{equation*}
We have
\begin{equation*}
x_i'x_j'=\sum_{k,\ell}R_{ik}R_{j\ell}x_kx_{\ell}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    \Downarrow 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    I_{x_i'x_j'}=-\int\sum_{k,\ell}R_{ik}R_{j\ell}x_{k}x_{\ell}=-\sum_{k,\ell}R_{ik}R_{j\ell}\int x_{k}x_{\ell}=\sum_{k,\ell}R_{ik}R_{j\ell}I_{k\ell}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    \Downarrow 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
 I'_{ij}=\sum_{k,\ell}R_{ik}R_{j\ell}I_{k\ell}
\end{equation*}
However, my method only works for $i\neq j$. I have no idea how to deal with the case where $i=j$, i.e the diagonal elements. Are there some instructions?

Comment: According to V.I. Arnold *Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics* the inertia tensor is a linear map that transforms angular velocities in the body coordinates into angular momenta. The rotation matrix is the transformation between body and space coordinates. Just as in ordinary linear algebra the transformation rule $\mathbf{I}'=\mathbf{RIR}^\top$ now follows. You don't need the specific form of $\mathbf{I}\,.$

Comment: One way is through the kinetic energy:

$T_r = 0.5 \omega^T_k I \omega_k $ which is equal to $T_r = 0.5 \omega^T_{k'} I' \omega_{k'} $.  

Also, $  \omega_k = R^T \omega_{k'}$ . So 
$ T = 0.5\omega^T_{k'} R I R^T \omega_{k'} $. 

Thus $I' =  R I R^T$